# abort() on core exception when ESP32 connect to web3

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I connected esp32 WROOM-32D to web3 with this library.
https://github.com/kopanitsa/web3-arduino

I tested the eth_send example of that library with both Arduino Ide and Platformio

After connecting to the Wifi the exception is like that

---

[SETUP] WAIT 4...
[SETUP] WAIT 3...
[SETUP] WAIT 2...
[SETUP] WAIT 1...
.Connected
abort() was called at PC 0x40162ff7 on core 1
Backtrace:0x40162ff7:0x3ffb23d00x4008cd21:0x3ffb23f0 0x40091ed1:0x3ffb2410 
0x40162ff7:0x3ffb2490 0x4016303e:0x3ffb24b0 0x40154283:0x3ffb24d0 0x40153d92:0x3ffb24f0
 0x40155275:0x3ffb2510 0x4015551d:0x3ffb2530
 0x400dddef:0x3ffb2560 0x400de337:0x3ffb2580 0x400d293a:0x3ffb2610 0x400d2ada:0x3ffb27f0
 0x400e0366:0x3ffb2820

---

I decoded the error exception with ESP exception Decoder and the error was decoded like this

```
Decoding stack results
0x400836f5: panic_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_system/panic.c line 402
0x4008cd21: esp_system_abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/esp_system/esp_system.c line 128
0x40091ed1: abort at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/newlib/abort.c line 46
0x40162ff7: __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc line 47
0x4016303e: std::terminate() at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc line 57
0x40154283: __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw(void*, std::type_info*, void (*)(void*)) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc line 95
0x40153d92: operator new(unsigned int) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/build/build-cc-gcc-final/xtensa-esp32-elf/no-rtti/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/exception.h line 63
0x40155275: std::__cxx11::basic_string  , std::allocator  >::_M_create(unsigned int&, unsigned int) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/build/build-cc-gcc-final/xtensa-esp32-elf/no-rtti/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h line 99
0x4015551d: std::__cxx11::basic_string  , std::allocator  >::reserve(unsigned int) at /builds/idf/crosstool-NG/.build/HOST-i686-w64-mingw32/xtensa-esp32-elf/build/build-cc-gcc-final/xtensa-esp32-elf/no-rtti/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h line 189
0x400dddef: std::operator+  , std::allocator  >(char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string  , std::allocator  > const&) at c:\users\yanna\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\bits/char_traits.h line 287
0x400de337: Web3::EthGetTransactionCount(std::__cxx11::basic_string  , std::allocator  > const*) (C:\Program Files at x86)\Arduino\libraries\web3-arduino\src\Web3.cpp line 137
0x400d293a: eth_send_example() at C:\Users\yanna\Documents\Arduino\basic_web3\eth_send/eth_send.ino line 53
0x400d2ada: setup() at C:\Users\yanna\Documents\Arduino\basic_web3\eth_send/eth_send.ino line 43
0x400e0366: loopTask(void*) at C:\Users\yanna\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.4\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 42
```

This is my codes

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Web3.h>
#include <Contract.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

const char* ssid = "V1A7C";
const char* password =  /*<password>*/;
#define MY_ADDRESS "0x1b9aE0Be6d87e79b9Bd5A6FcDc67d92F76F6e0F6"
#define CONTRACT_ADDRESS "0xDA832c3825A37d693d17D9360d5289B8B2b580f0"
#define INFURA_HOST "eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io"
#define INFURA_PATH "/v2/1yNgxbZKvL4JzOIjnNUywYue0ruh_Fjt"

const char PRIVATE_KEY[] = {/*<32 bytes of private key>*/};
                            
Web3 web3((string*)INFURA_HOST, (string*)INFURA_PATH);

void eth_send_example();

void setup() {
    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);

    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
        USE_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        // wait 1 second for re-trying
        delay(1000);
    }

    USE_SERIAL.println("Connected");

    eth_send_example();
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

void eth_send_example() {
    Contract contract(&web3,(string*) CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    contract.SetPrivateKey((uint8_t*)PRIVATE_KEY);
    uint32_t nonceVal = (uint32_t)web3.EthGetTransactionCount((string *)MY_ADDRESS);

    uint32_t gasPriceVal = 141006540;
    uint32_t  gasLimitVal = 3000000;
    uint8_t toStr[] = CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
    uint8_t valueStr[] = "0x00";
    uint8_t dataStr[100];
    memset(dataStr, 0, 100);
    string func = "mint(uint256)";
    string p = contract.SetupContractData(&func, 123);
    string result = contract.SendTransaction(nonceVal, gasPriceVal, gasLimitVal, (string*) &toStr,(string*) &valueStr,(string*) &p);

    Serial.println(result);
}
```

Comment: @DavidFong the private key I posted was edited and it's fake. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting C char pointers to std::string pointers like this.

```
#define MY_ADDRESS "..."
...
uint32_t nonceVal = (uint32_t)web3.EthGetTransactionCount((string *)MY_ADDRESS);
```

Don't do that. If you need a pointer to a `string`, you should create an instance of the `string` like this.

```
string address = MY_ADDRESS;
uint32_t nonceVal = (uint32_t)web3.EthGetTransactionCount(&address);
```

As a side note, I don't recommend to use the web3-arduino.(I am very certain that the author of that library is a novice on C++.)

Comment: I just defined MY_ADDRESS like this

const char* myAddress = "<my address>";

It didn't work . I'm not proficient in C++ , so could you pls show me how to solve it ?

Comment: I added the example code as you wanted. But I am certain you will waste your time if you use C++ without knowing basics of C++.